# Java probability if 2 integers are coprime

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to write a programme that outputs the probability that the two randomly selected numbers are coprime

- Two integers are coprime if the only positive integer that divides into both of them
  is 1. In other words, the greatest common divisor of two coprime numbers is 1.
- If two numbers x and y are selected randomly, the odds that they will be coprime
  with each other is 61% (6 divided by PI^2). But what if we put some restrictions on
  the two numbers? For example, if x is a randomly selected number that is divisible
  by 7 and y is a randomly selected number that is divisible by 13? In this case, the
  odds that they are coprime is 49%.
- I am given a divisor of the first number and a divisor of the
  second number. I must then output an integer from 0 to 100, which is the
  percentage probability that the two randomly selected numbers are coprime.

here is what I have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static int myTestMethod(int a, int b)
    //method taking two numbers a and b 
    {
        //Calculating gcd because if gcd is 1 then a and b are //coprimes. 
        if (b == 0)
            return a;
        else
            return myTestMethod(b, a % b);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a and b");
        int y;
        float p = 0;
        //taking inputs a and b two numbers. 
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        //Calculating gcd by calling method
        y = (myTestMethod(a, b));
        System.out.print("gcd is:");
        System.out.println(y);
        p = (myTestMethod(a, b));
        //if gcd is 1 the probability should be 1 
        if (y == 1) {
            System.out.println("probability is:");
            System.out.println(p);
        }
        //else print probability as p/100.
        else {
            System.out.println("The probability is :");
            System.out.println(p / 100);
        }
    }
}
```

is this the correct way to go about it?

Comment: Hello, you should format the code with a formatter and add the missing method `myTestMethod`.

Comment: Did you test it? Does it print 0.49 for inputs 7 and 13?

Comment: (FYI, from a mathematical point of view, a "randomly selected integer" doesn't quite exist.  You can make sense of the statement if you're being careful, and that ends up giving you the 6/π^2.)

Comment: @vnp, I've tried and it gave me the result: `gcd is:1` and `probability is: 1.0` for an input `7` and `13`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that makes it an off-topic here. We may only review the code that works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This review is for the code only, not the optimization / correctness; I assume the code works as IS.

### Avoid using `C-style` array declaration

In the main method, you declared a `C-style` array declaration with the `args` variable.

**before**

```java
String args[]
```

**after**

```java
String[] args
```

In my opinion, this style is less used and can cause confusion.

### Always add curly braces to `loop` & `if`

In my opinion, it's a bad practice to have a block of code not surrounded by curly braces; I saw so many bugs in my career related to that, if you forget to add the braces when adding code, you break the logic / semantic of the code.

**Before**

```java
if (b == 0)
   return a;
else
   return myTestMethod(b, a % b);
```

**After**

```java
if (b == 0) {
   return a;
} else {
   return myTestMethod(b, a % b);
}
```

### Other things

#### To save space in the main method, you can inline the variable `y` and `p`

```java
//[...]
int y = (myTestMethod(a, b));
//[...]
float p = (myTestMethod(a, b));
//[...]
```

#### You can take less lines for the printing in the main method

You can make a printing method

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
   if (y == 1) {  //if gcd is 1 the probability should be 1
      printMultiLine("probability is:", p);
   } else { //else print probability as p/100.
      printMultiLine("The probability is :", p / 100);
   }
}

private static void printMultiLine(String message, float value) {
   System.out.println(message);
   System.out.println(value);
}
```

**or**

You can uses `java.io.PrintStream#printf`

`java.io.PrintStream#printf` offer you to use [patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) to build the string without concatenating it manually. The only downside is you will be forced to add the break line character yourself; in java you can use the `%n` to break the line (portable between various platforms) or uses the traditional `\n` / `\r\n`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
   //[...]
   if (y == 1) {  //if gcd is 1 the probability should be 1
      System.out.printf("probability is:%n%f", p);
   } else { //else print probability as p/100.
      System.out.printf("The probability is:%n%f", p / 100);
   }
}
```